# Java Program to print all odd integers up to N and print 10 integer per line

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I'm having a little trouble with my program. I already wrote my user validation and I can print all odd numbers up to what the user inputed. My problem is trying to get 10 integers on every line. Obviously, I tried the i % 10 == 0 technique and as you know odd number can't have a remainder of zero. If you could give some tips or guidance that's be fantastic!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Question {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        System.out.print("Please enter a number. ");
        n = input.nextInt();

        while(n < 0 || n > 1000){
           System.out.print("Error: 0 <= N <= 1000. Reenter.");
           n = input.nextInt();
         }

        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i+=1) {
            System.out.print(" " + i);
            if(i % 10 == 0)
             System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't believe everyone is using a for loop, incrementing by one, and testing for `i % 2 == 1`.  Why not start at 1 and increment by 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following logic seems to work:

```
for (int i=1; i <= n; i+=1) {
    if (i % 2 == 1)
        System.out.print(" " + i);
    if (i % 20 == 0)
        System.out.print("\n");
}
```

The basic idea here is that the `(i % 2 == 1)` condition prints only odd numbers, and the `(i % 20 == 0)` adds a line break every *ten* numbers.  The reason we use mod 20 is that there are *ten* odd numbers for every 20 counting numbers.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i+=1) {
    if (i % 2 == 1){
     System.out.print(" " + i);
     count += 1;
     continue;}

    if(count % 10 == 0)
     System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Adding a count which only increases when an odd number is printed means that you can test to see if it is divisible by 10.